# Skim Coating: Steps? Weight of joint compound?

Tags: repainting

I need to skim coat a couple walls with a knockdown texture ([example](http://sawdustgirl.com/how-to-get-rid-of-ugly-wall-texture-skim-coating/)).

1) What are the steps I need to take? I've seen that I need to clean the walls with TSP? Should this be done along with sanding?

2) What weight of joint compoud should be used? I've seen Lite recommeneded, I've seen that it doesn't matter, I've seen super-lite. Which is best? It is my assumtion that lite is best so that it dries quicker and won't add as much extra weight to the wall, but I have no idea what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1):

I've done a lot of skim coating, mostly on old plaster walls.

If you're thoroughly sanding the walls, using TSP is not necessary. Just vacuum and wipe the dust off after before you coat. If you're going directly over a painted surface then TSP or other cleaning is helpful.

I've used lightweight joint compound. I prefer the setting kind (that you mix from powder and sets after a fixed time) and find the 120min set to be easy enough to work with. Setting compound is *incredibly* sticky and provides a long-lasting finish.

Get yourself the right tools (esp. wide-blade knives) and give yourself some time/space to practice. It's an art.

Answer (score 0):

Whether you need to clean the walls depends on the walls (which I can't see from here). Normally you can apply compound right over fairly clean latex paint. You may want to do a test blop (industry term) and see if it pops off the paint.

Compound weight is a matter of personal preference, mostly. Standard (with vinyl) may bond better, but is heavier to work with. Lightweight is easier to apply. Topping compound has more of a whipped feel, which I've never really found useful. It also shrinks more, so you may end up skimming an additional time.

Comment: Thank you! I've read that lite also dents and scratches a bit easier. Is this the case even after priming and painting?

Comment: Yeah, but only marginally. Any modern drywall finish is pretty fragile compared to plaster.